# amazon ec2, cannot ping internal host

Tags: amazon-ec2

In amazon ec2, I have 2 instances in a placement group. First node is 172.31.12.76/20, second, 172.31.12.77/20 I can ssh both nodes from my pc. They share the same security group that has got these 2 rules:

Inbound rules:

```
Type        Protocol    Port Range    Source
SSH         TCP         22            0.0.0.0/0
All IMCP    All         N/A           0.0.0.0/0
```

(no outbound rules)

Both nodes see to each  other in L2:

```
root@ip-172-31-12-76:~# arp
[...]
ip-172-31-12-77.eu-west  ether   0a:ad:5e:e4:12:de   C                     eth0
[...]

root@ip-172-31-12-77:~# arp
[...]
ip-172-31-12-76.eu-west  ether   0a:34:a1:17:57:28   C                     eth0
[...]
```

iptables are empty on both nodes.

But ping does not work between each other

I have already checked a previous post: 
[EC2 instances not responding to internal ping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6176813/ec2-instances-not-responding-to-internal-ping) 
but it does not address the issue. It looks like there are no other similar posts.

Any idea? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer; I need to also allow outbound icmp on each host in order to be able to ping both external and internal IPs.