# bidding spot 3 volumn, why internal ping does not work

Tags: amazon-ec2

I got 3 instances of ec2 in aws. I try to ping each other, then according to [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25471644/amazon-ec2-cannot-ping-internal-host), I issue the command to enable ICMP on each node.

```
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_all=0
```

But I still could not ping, what's the problem? any suggestions?

Comment: What exactly does your security group look like? Do you have any network ACLs for your VPC?

Comment: after VPC's default security group is added,  ping functions! Thank you Sathed!